# Varying memcached action caching by domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I use Memcached (actually, Memcachier on Heroku) for action caching in a Rails 3 app like so:

```
caches_action :index, :expires_in => 14.days
```

The problem is that my app is accessed from a number of different domains and the content needs to vary. Currently, it is cached the same for all domains. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails [`caches_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html) documentation says:

> Action caching uses fragment caching internally and an around filter
>   to do the job. The fragment cache is named according to the host and
>   path of the request. A page that is accessed at
>   http://david.example.com/lists/show/1 will result in a fragment named
>   david.example.com/lists/show/1. This allows the cacher to
>   differentiate between david.example.com/lists/ and
>   jamis.example.com/lists/ – which is a helpful way of assisting the
>   subdomain-as-account-key pattern.

So the generated keys should be differ for different domains.

To check it I even created an application with `:mem_cache_store` and started a memcached server in verbose mode (`-vv`).

The requests/responses looked like this for `http://localhost:3000/`:

```
<21 get views/localhost:3000/index
>21 END
<21 set views/localhost:3000/index 0 0 7123
>21 STORED
```

With a different domain `http://foobar:3000/`:

```
<21 get views/foobar:3000/index
>21 END
<21 set views/foobar:3000/index 0 0 7123
>21 STORED
```

#### Update

If you want to create different cache keys depending on the request and the default is not enough for you, then you can use the [`:cache_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html) option of `caches_action`.

You can find examples in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483847/how-can-caches-action-be-configured-to-work-for-multiple-formats).

Comment: I think the OP was thinking about serving different content to different people, depending on their location (geo, or whatever).